# Why does this code throw a "Useless use of anonymous hash ({}) in void context" warning.

Tags: perl

I'm re-factoring a Perl program I inherited.  The following line

```
(! exists $self->{DEVEL}) &&  { @$d = $nsaobj->filter_list(@$d) };
```

is throwing the following warning...

```
Useless use of anonymous hash ({}) in void context...
```

First I want to understand what is happening here.  Am I correct that this is just a different way of writing the statement below?

```
if (! exists $self->{DEVEL}) {
   @$d = $nsaobj->filter_list(@$d);
}
```

My best guess is that the original line works due to lazy evaluation, if so, what is the rational to writing it that way?

Second, why does this particular line throw the "useless use.." warning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> First I want to understand what is happening here. Am I correct that this is just a different way of writing the statement below?

Yes, it seems like that's the intent of the original code, however that's not exactly what it is doing.  Perl's warning is correct.  The original author likely meant to write

```
(! exists $self->{DEVEL}) && do { @$d = $nsaobj->filter_list(@$d); };
```

The `do` is the important part here as it states to execute the subsequent block.  Without the `do`, Perl instead creates an anonymous hash reference with the contents of `@$d` but that value is then not bound to any variable, hence the warning.  It could even result in a runtime error if `@$d` ends up being an array with an odd number of elements.

If there's a desire to keep this as a one-liner, this would be a more typical construct

```
@$d = $nsaobj->filter_list(@$d) unless exists $self->{DEVEL};
```

Comment: Nice answer, thanks. Short of making the code a one-liner, is there a valid reason for not writing this as an "if" statement?

Comment: Not that I can think of.  If you still wanted a one-liner, you could do the more typical `@$d = $nsaobj->filter_list(@$d) unless exists $self->{DEVEL};`

Answer (score -1):

Perl considers the part after `&&` to be an anonymous hash reference. You can omit the braces `{` and `}` as it is a single command anyway, and the warning would disappear.